# Project images are shown in gallery

Tags: android, image, hide, gallery

I am still working on my first app. My problem is that all my images are shown in the gallery. How can I prevent that?

Comment: I got another way. Just add a .nomedia-File to the folder of the project and all your sounds and pictures won't be displayed in the gallery.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did it, just add an File to your projectfolder called ".NOMEDIA" and android wont show it in the gallary and your sounds aren't shown in the music-app

Comment: Its a nice way to prevent it from being it done programatically!

Answer (score 1):

You should save your images in internal location like this

```
private String saveToInternalSorage(Bitmap bitmapImage){
    ContextWrapper cw = new ContextWrapper(getApplicationContext());
     // path to /data/data/yourapp/app_data/imageDir
    File directory = cw.getDir("imageDir", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    // Create imageDir
    File mypath=new File(directory,"profile.jpg");

    FileOutputStream fos = null;
    try {           

        fos = new FileOutputStream(mypath);

   // Use the compress method on the BitMap object to write image to the OutputStream
        bitmapImage.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, fos);
        fos.close();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return directory.getAbsolutePath();
}
```